# Matlab runs very slower (almost stucks) after some iteration in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ram

In my program I have a for loop which has to run 5823x8153 times. The for loop runs quite faster until i= 3944 and j = 8153. However, after this point the for loop is running very slowly almost it stucks at this point. I tried some acceleration methods like pre allocation and computing some variables before the for loop but it did not work. The problematic for loop is given as below. Could you please help me about this problem? By the way, it works good for small portions(1000x1000 or 3000x3000) of the same data and I run this program using a workstation with 64GB RAM. I am looking forward to hearing from you

```
ro1 = (180*3600)/pi;
ro = ro1^2;  
sigma_h = horizontal_prec_secs;
sigma_v = vertical_prec_secs;
error_ellip_dim = nan(5823,8153,3);
for i = 1:5823
    for j = 1:8153
        sigma_r = range_precision(i,j);
        h = horizontal_angle(i,j);
        v = vertical_angle(i,j);
        r = range(i,j)*1000;
        if (isnan(h))||(isnan(sigma_r))
           error_ellip_dim(i,j,:) = NaN;
        else
            EXX(1,1) = sigma_r^2*COSDH(i,j)^2*COSDV(i,j)^2 + (r^2*sigma_h^2*COSDV(i,j)^2*SINDH(i,j)^2)/ro + (r^2*sigma_v^2*COSDH(i,j)^2*SINDV(i,j)^2)/ro;
            EXX(1,2) = sigma_r^2*COSDH(i,j)*COSDV(i,j)^2*SINDH(i,j) - (r^2*sigma_h^2*COSDH(i,j)*COSDV(i,j)^2*SINDH(i,j))/ro + (r^2*sigma_v^2*COSDH(i,j)*SINDH(i,j)*SINDV(i,j)^2)/ro;
            EXX(1,3) = COSDH(i,j)*COSDV(i,j)*SINDV(i,j)*sigma_r^2 - (r^2*sigma_v^2*COSDH(i,j)*COSDV(i,j)*SINDV(i,j))/ro;
            EXX(2,1) = EXX(1,2); 
            EXX(2,2) = sigma_r^2*COSDV(i,j)^2*SINDH(i,j)^2 + (r^2*sigma_h^2*COSDH(i,j)^2*COSDV(i,j)^2)/ro + (r^2*sigma_v^2*SINDH(i,j)^2*SINDV(i,j)^2)/ro;
            EXX(2,3) = COSDV(i,j)*SINDH(i,j)*SINDV(i,j)*sigma_r^2 - (r^2*sigma_v^2*COSDV(i,j)*SINDH(i,j)*SINDV(i,j))/ro;
            EXX(3,1) = EXX(1,3);
            EXX(3,2) = EXX(2,3);
            EXX(3,3) = sigma_r^2*SINDV(i,j)^2 + (r^2*sigma_v^2*COSDV(i,j)^2)/ro;
            [eig_vec_mat,eig_val_mat] = eig(EXX);
            ellip_params = sqrt(diag(eig_val_mat));
            error_ellip_dim(i,j,:) = ellip_params';            
        end
    end
    i
    j
end
```

Comment: What is the output from matlab's profiler when you reduce the loop indexes to allow it to finish, but leave them large enough to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: You can try `conditional breakpoint` by right-clicking on the breakpoint bar. You can set `i==3944 && j==8153`, then go step by step and see where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for helps. I figured out the problem. At the point where it stucks, MAtlab is trying to compute square root of a negative number and getting complex number. And it is spending great effort for this job. I avoided from these numbers by a simple codification and it is running quite rapidly.